Understand the `CopyAssignable` in the right way
When I am using stl, I find that non-assignable types are not allowed as components of containers.
But the CopyAssignable concept is really hard to master/understand, which requires to dig into the lvalue expression concept and MoveAssignable concept. It's a nightmare. Is there any other easier way to master this concept other than reading the linked page line by line?
As per the boost documet about  assignable, which says that:

Description
Assignable types must have copy constructors, operator=
for assignment, and the swap() function defined.

The assignable described on Boost website is really easy to understand.
I want to know whether these two aforementioned concepts are the same thing or not.

Basically yes, they're supposed to be equivalent. But the standard c++ version is just being more thorough.

"really hard to master/understand" -- Which are you interested in? Mastering the concept does require understanding other concepts and subtleties of meaning, but understanding it is really simple (assignment works as expected; given T t; and T v;, the assignment t = v copies the value of v to t without changing v). Understanding is typically enough to use containers; mastering is useful if you are implementing containers.

In this case, Boost describes what the type must have as members (implying valid expressions), while C++ describes expressions that are valid (implying existing members).

Do you want to master the concept, or be able to use it?  The boost description is easy to understand and insufficient to actually know what it says: you have to read the implementation to understand it, and that implementation is the real meaning.  The standard description is difficult to understand but sufficient: it specifies what the implementation has to do; the implementation if it has quirks has bugs.  To master the boost version, read the source code: to master the C++ standard version, learn standardese.  In both cases, use does not require mastery.

The boost concept Assignable is the combination of the standard concepts CopyAssignable, CopyConstructible, and Swappable. It is common for a type to model either all of them, or none of them, but the standard is more granular in what it defines here.
The wordings for those standard concepts precisely define what "have copy constructors", "have operator=", and "have swap" respectively, are.
